# How to ensure Static Properties get initialized after Global.Application_Start code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I ensure that the Factory class' properties get initialized after Application_Start?

```
public static class Globals
{
      public Static Customer Cust {get;set;}
}

public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Globals.Cust = GetCustomerFromDataBase();
    }
}

public static class Factory    
{
     public static Customer Cust => Globals.Cust ; 
}
```

The Factory.Customer gets called by a method inside a webapi controller.

Comment: Who consumes Factory.Cust?  That property isn't "initialized", it gets consumed, and, when it's referenced, it goes and fetches Globals.Cust.  So your question becomes "Does anyone call the Factory.Cust getter before WebApiApplication.Application_Start() gets called".  That's all in your code

Comment: It gets called by a method inside a webapi controller. I made the edit with this information.

Comment: @Flydog57 So if I understand you right, you are saying (in my case) until a webapi method accesses the factory class' property, it won't get initialized? even if i'm using Lazy<T>?

Comment: Well, Application_Start should happen before any WebAPI controller code runs, so you should be all set.  Are you seeing issues?  Have you put breakpoints in your code to see what kind of ordering is happening

Comment: I haven't seen any issues, but didn't want to rollout to production without knowing for sure of the order.

Comment: No, I'm saying that static constructors run "some time before" any references are made to that class.  And, if you initialize a field, that initialization becomes part of the constructor.  But, you have no initialization.  Your Cust property just delegates to a static property of the Globals class.  Without initialization, there's no ordering at all

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you completely. Would you mind explaining this an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: This use case sounds like a great one to use the [C# Lazy type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx). It allow you to declare the static global Cust instance and the actual initialization doesn't occur until the very first request accesses it. It also has the advantage that the initialization process is thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on your code.  If as you say, `Factory.Cust` is first referenced in a WebAPI Controller method, then you should be safe; the `Application_Start` method should have run before anything in one of your controllers.

Your `Factory.Cust` property doesn't get initialized.  When someone tries to read the value of `Factory.Cust`, all that happens is that the `Globals.Cust` property (getter) is executed (remember, properties are really code, not just state).  As long as `Globals.Cust` is initialized before `Factory.Cust` is read, you are safe.  If you test your code (by putting breakpoints here and there) and it seems to follow what I'm saying, you should be OK.

What I was saying in the comments about static classes is that a static class can have a constructor.  It can be explicit (you write a constructor for the class), but it can also have other code you have in your class.  For example, if, in your Factory class, you had code that looked like:

```
private static Customer _localCustomerStuff = new Customer();
```

Then the code that's associated with that field would be folded into the Factory constructor.  Property initializers like the one below also do the same kind of thing (since they are initializing the hidden *backing store* for the property).

```
public static string SomeString { get; set; } = "SomeString Initial Value";
```

You don't know exactly when a static class's constructor code will run, but there is a guarantee made by the framework that it will run **before** any reference to that class is made.  If you access the Factory class, and you had some initialization associated with that class (none of which you show in your post above), then you can be sure that the initialization will have started before you access anything to do with the class.

Take a look at [Static Constructor Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) to see what I'm talking about.